# Close search "help" box on unfocus

Tags: bug, status-review, search, top-bar, accessibility

I don't specifically require any accessibility features, but I prefer to use the site with my keyboard sometimes. When I tab through the link/input fields the help box that appears below the top-bar search box remains open even after I tab past the search field, obscuring the page.  Fixing this would improve the user experience of folks like me who forego the mouse because they prefer to, and surely would improve the experience of those with motor disabilities who forego the mouse because they have to.

[image]

Notice in the image that I am currently focused on the hamburger menu, but the search help is still open, obscuring a pretty big chunk of the page.  Since the search bar is one of the "early" input fields in the page, it pops up basically as soon as I start tabbing through the links/fields, and remains up in perpetuity.  Actually, the tags field (when asking a question) does a similar thing, and probably there exist other fields on the site that behave similarly. The one that is most apparent in terms of the UX is the search bar (again, because it is so early in the page, and because it covers relevant content.)

Comment: I'm 99% sure I saw a similar post about this exact problem recently but I can't find it at all.

Comment: (As a note, the hamburger menu is what's displayed if "Hide left navigation" is enabled in your user settings. That said, this issue is true regardless of what you tab to.)

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I'm also remembering seeing something quite similar, but I have the vague impression that the request was the opposite (i.e. not close the search help popup when the search field lost focus). IIRC, it was so that the things within the "search help" box could be interacted with, rather than just be able to make a single click. Maybe I'm completely misremembering it.

Comment: @Makyen I think you're referring to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382846/348196). And no, that's not it.

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, the hamburger menu is just what happened to be selected as I was tabbing frantically to get the search popup to appear before the 5s window of my screencapture app elapsed.  :)

Comment: @Makyen Found it (finally! :-D). It was on MSO: [The search dropdown does not hide when it loses focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419744/8967612)

Comment: If this negatively affects you, there is a workaround: just hit the "escape" key at any time and the search box disappears. You can do this even if you are not focused on search.

Comment: The fix should preserve tab -> shift+tab being a no-op – that is, shift+tab on the profile link should go to search help if nothing else changes. (I don't know how to make the web browser do such a thing.)